# Why does my Image animation code not work?

Tags: html, css, image, animation

I'm working on an animation with css and html but my animation isn't working.

https://www.abroprojectafbouw.nl/

Here is an example how it should look if its done (you need to scroll down) and here is my code. The black screen is always jumping back. Thank you for Help!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  animation: change 0.5s ease-out;
  height: 70vw;
}

.img {
  background-image: url("https://www.abroprojectafbouw.nl/wp-content/uploads/moddit-fly-images/468/foto-15-scaled-770x500-c.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vw;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vw;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: slide 0.5s ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="img">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `.img` and [`forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) to slide animation.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  animation: change 0.5s ease-out;
  height: 70vw;
}

.img {
  background-image: url("https://www.abroprojectafbouw.nl/wp-content/uploads/moddit-fly-images/468/foto-15-scaled-770x500-c.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vw;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation: slide 0.5s ease-out forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="img">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```